# MySQL: Get all rows using each one's parent

Tags: mysql

Not to sure how to write an accurate title but my problem should be an easy as I'm at a very beginning stage of using MySQL.

> Table `projects` (81 rows)

The `project` ID: **2**.

> Table `project_industry` (158 rows)

| project_id | industry_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 81 |
| 2 | 92 |
| 2 | 115 |
| 2 | 200 |

> Table `industries` (369 rows)

| id | parent_id | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | ビジネス領域 |
| 7 | 1 | 生活用品・サービス |
| 8 | 1 | 教育 |
| 10 | 1 | 建設 |
| 21 | 1 | エレクトロニクス |
| 81 | 7 | シニア |
| 92 | 8 | EdTech |
| 115 | 10 | i-Construction(ICT土木) |
| 200 | 21 | 家電 |

My thought is to get all deepest industry `id` from table `project_industry`. Then use the parent ID of these rows to get the father industries and then to get grand father industries (parent_id: 0).

> Here is my dummy script:

```
select id, parent_id, label from `industries` i 
    where id in (
        select pi.industry_id from `project_industry` pi where pi.project_id = 2
    )
union 
select id, parent_id, label from `industries` i 
where id in(
    select parent_id from `industries` i 
    where id in (
        select pi.industry_id from `project_industry` pi where pi.project_id = 2
        )
    )
union 
select id, parent_id, label from `industries` i 
where id in (
    select parent_id from `industries` i where id in(
        select parent_id from `industries` i where id in (
            select pi.industry_id from `project_industry` pi where pi.project_id = 2
        )
    )
)
```

The above script can get me the result I was expected. But by looking at so many duplicated `SELECT` I think my script is the most inefficient one and they must be so many efficient and elegant ways to achieve the same result quicker and simpler.

Appreciate if anyone can show me the path of how to improve this implementation.

**Update**

Below is the result I get from the query.

```
id    parent_id    label
81    7            シニア
92    8            EdTech
115   10           i-Construction(ICT土木)
200   21           家電
7     1            生活用品・サービス
8     1            教育
10    1            建設
21    1            エレクトロニクス
1     0            ビジネス領域
```

Also here is my JS code to make it to a tree.

```
let tmp = {};
if (rows.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i ++) {
        if (!rows[i].parent_id) {
            let t1 = {
                label: rows[i].label,
                children: []
            };
            for (let m = 0; m < rows.length; m ++) {
                if (!rows[m].parent_id === rows[i].id) {
                    let t2 = {
                        label: rows[m].label,
                        children: []
                    };
                    for (let n = 0; n < rows.length; n ++) {
                        if (!rows[n].parent_id === rows[m].id) {
                            t2.children.push({ label: rows[n].label });
                        }
                    }
                    t1.children.push(t2);
                }
            }
            tmp[rows[i].id] = t1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide the expected resultset

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf850732aacfb72bd905da22a089727d

Comment: Thanks and that looks great but unfortunately my mysql is 5.7 which throws an error on `WITH RECURSIVE`

Comment: In which case: Upgrade!